# Mongoengine and add_to_set doesn't seem to be working

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I'm trying to save references to mp3's to a database. I'm saving artist, song, and album to their own respective schemas and referencing between them via ReferenceFields.

I'm using eyeD3 to parse id3 data, if there is any, and save that to the database. My problem is that I want to save all three schema types at the same time but I might going about it the wrong way. I'm using python 2.7.10.

example schema:

```
class Artist(db.Document):
    """Schema for Artist"""
    name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True, unique=True)
    albums = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Album'))
    songs = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Song'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Album(db.Document):
    """Schema for albums"""
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True, unique=True)
    artist = db.ReferenceField(Artist)
    songs = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Song'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Song(db.Document):
    """Schema for songs"""
    title = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True, unique=True)
    artist = db.ReferenceField(Artist)
    album = db.ReferenceField(Album)
    path = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and the code to save to db:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for f in files:
        if '.mp3' in f:
            id3 = eyed3.load(os.path.join(root, f))
            song = Song(title=id3.tag.title, path=os.path.join(root, f))
            album = Album(title=id3.tag.album)
            artist = Artist(name=id3.tag.artist)

            song.save()
            album.save()
            artist.save()
            Artist.objects(id=artist.id).update(add_to_set__albums=album, add_to_set__songs=song)
            Album.objects(id=album.id).update(artist=artist, add_to_set__songs=song)
            Song.objects(id=song.id).update(artist=artist, album=album)
```

After saving, add_to_set is only saving one object to each ListField instead of pushing it on to the end.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the culprit. Because some attributes of the schema are unique, when I assign an object to a variable that is already inserted into the db:

```
artist = Artist(name=id3.artist)
```

it returns a dulpicate error. Then I try to use that variable to push to another object:

```
Album.objects(title=id3.album).update(artist=artist)
```

but that variable is not set due to the duplicate error.

Here is my refactored code using upserts:

```
Song.objects(title=song.tag.title).update(path=path, upsert=True)
so = Song.objects.get(title=song.tag.title)
Album.objects(title=song.tag.album).update(add_to_set__songs=so, upsert=True)
al = Album.objects.get(title=song.tag.album)
Artist.objects(name=song.tag.artist).update(add_to_set__songs=so, add_to_set__albums=al, upsert=True)
ar = Artist.objects.get(name=song.tag.artist)
so.update(artist=ar, album=al)
al.update(artist=ar, add_to_set__songs=so)
```